# Highcharts js - ¿Es posible cambiar el color de las categorías en el eje x al presionar sobre un tooltip?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

quisiera hacer una consulta acerca de la librería Highcharts ya que aún estoy practicando con esta no conozco mucho sobre esta. ¿Es posible cambiar el color de una categoría luego de que se presione sobre su valor?

Este es el gráfico que estoy utilizando

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
          text: null
        },
        
    chart: {
      type: "areaspline",
      spacingLeft: 0,
      spacingRight: 0,
      zoomType: 'x',
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var chart = this,
            series = this.series[0],
            xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
            newStart = series.xData[1],
            newEnd = series.xData[7];

          xAxis.setExtremes(newStart, newEnd);
        }
      }
    },
    
    tooltip: {
          pointFormat: "<b>{point.y}</b>",
          backgroundColor: null,
          style: {
            color: "#F37198",
            padding: 0,
            fontSize: "18px"
          },
          shadow: 0,
          borderWidth: 0,
          outside: true,
          useHTML: true,
          formatter: function() {
            return "<b>" + this.y + "</b>";
          }
        },
    
    plotOptions: {
          areaspline: {
            color: "#fdd4db",
            lineColor: "#f37198",
            lineWidth: 2.5,
            marker: {
              enabled: true,
              symbol: "circle",
              radius: 6,
              fillColor: "#f37198",
              lineColor: "white",
              lineWidth: 2,
              states: {
                hover: {
                  enabled: true,
                  radiusPlus: 0,
                  lineWidthPlus: 0
                  
                }
              }
            },
            states: {
             hover: {
               lineWidthPlus: 0,
               halo: {
                 opacity: 0.5,
                  size: 16,
                  attributes: {
                                fill: "#f15887",
                    }
                },
              },
            },
          }
        },

    xAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    categories: ['28/04', '29/04', '30/04', '01/05', '02/05', '03/05', '04/05', '05/05', '06/05'],
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    gridLineColor: '#F3F0F0',
    tickmarkPlacement:'on',
    lineWidth: 0,
    opposite: true,
    startOnTick: true,
    labels: {
            style: { color: "#B3B2B2" , fontSize: "14px" , textOverflow : "none" },
          },
    },
    
    legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
    
    yAxis: {
          visible: false,
        },

    series: [{
        data: [0, 12.2, 8.6, 7.6, 8.1, 7.9, 10.1, 7.5, 0],
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

[image: Click sobre el Marcador]

[image: Cambia el Color del label]

Agradecería mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro que si se puede, necesitas manejar el evento `click` en los `point` asi:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        this.color="red";
                        $($(".highcharts-axis-labels:first text")[this.index]).css({fill: "red"});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: Disculpe, no explique bien lo que necesitaba. Lo que busco es que la categoría "30/04" cambie al color rojo cuando presiono sobre el marcador con el valor "8.6"

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Conseguí una solución gracias a esta respuesta

https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=42012&p=147168#p147168

Aquí adjunto el gráfico que muestra lo que necesito

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qLmhz78d/

Comment: Aunque esto teoricamente solucione la pregunta, [seria preferible](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) que incluyas las partes esenciales en la respuesta aqui, y dejes el link solo como referencia. Las respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad

Comment: De acuerdo lo tendré en cuenta gracias